# 'Index was outside the bounds of the array' changing 2D int values

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm quite new to C# and I made this which creates a 5x5 grid which increases each number in the grid by `1` so the grid counts up.

```
    public static void Main () {

        int width = 5;
        int height = 5;

        int gridNumber = 0;

        int[,] grid = new int[height, width];

            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {

                if (grid [x,y] + (gridNumber +1) < 10){
                    Console.Write (grid [x,y] + (gridNumber + 1) + "  | " );
                }
                else if (grid [x,y] + (gridNumber +1) == 10) {
                    Console.Write (grid [x,y] + (gridNumber + 1) + " |" );
                }
                else {
                    Console.Write (grid [x,y] + (gridNumber + 1) + " | " );
                }

                gridNumber++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine ();

        }

        Console.ReadKey ();
    }
```

My problem is whenever I change the grid dimensions (changing either `int` from a `5` to anything else), I get an error saying `Index was outside the bounds of the array`.

`int width = 5;`

`int height = 5;`

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Are you changing *both* width and height to be the same *new* value? Because you swap your checks in the `for` loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
int[,] grid = new int[height, width];
```

to

```
int[,] grid = new int[width, height];
```

Comment: That is a stupid answer the index out of bounds exception remains..... It has nothing to do with the ops question

Comment: While it may not fix the problem, it does attempt to point out the swap of width and height from declaration to usage (which *would* matter very much if height and width were different - i.e. still something that needs to be looked at).

Comment: @Blaatz0r I think there is some confusion here. OP is using grid[x,y] but has defined x as Width and y as Height. The Order of index does matter in array. And I feel that is the only issue here

Comment: @Crashmstr he should have added it to the comments. Since it isn't an answer.

Comment: @Blaatz0r The OP does not say if he changes one or both numbers and if they are still equal to each other. If he changes them to *not* be equal, than this is exactly the answer.

Comment: @Blaatz0r I'm sure this fixes the problem as OP has asked "Any ideas on how to fix this?"

Comment: @Anup in this case they are equal so here it doesn't matter it starts to matter if his 2d is inequal eg. Width 6 height 5

Comment: @Blaatz0r Stop nitpicking and read the question - it works for `5, 5`, but breaks when the OP changes one of the dimensions. This *is* the correct answer.

Comment: @Blaatz0r Please Read the question once again "My problem is whenever I change the grid dimensions"